# Удобство namespace в PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm, yii2, namespace

Как упростить программирование с использованием пространств имен?

Импорт каждого класса вручную - неудобно.

Есть ли в *IDE* типа *PHPStorm* функция, аналогичная *Resolve* в *MS Visual Studio*, чтобы при написании названия класса можно было одним кликом найти его и добавить в `use`?

Comment: PHPStrom все прекрасно находит, если правильно все сконфигурировано. Для подключения классов используйте autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду автоимпорт пространства имен? Для PHPStorm посмотрите [эту статью](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/creating-imports.html).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте требуемые библиотеки для проекта в Languages - PHP - Includes